# Not recognizing command line argument in Python

Tags: python, command-line-arguments

I am trying to add a command line argument depending on some values returned by the functions. When I am not giving that argument it says:

```
main.py: error: argument -opp/--operator is required
```

When I am giving the argument it says:

```
main.py: error: unrecognized arguments: -opp +
```

Following is the piece of  EDITED code (as told in one of the answers):

```
parser.add_argument('-z', help='Help msg', required=True)
args, unknown = parser.parse_known_args()
value = some_functions(args.z)
if value == some_particular_value:
    parser.add_argument('-opp','--operator',help='Some help msg',required=True)
args = parser.parse_args()
```

Please help me in adding this argument. Thanks!

Comment: The argument given with one `-` has to be one character only, e.g. `-o`.

Comment: @KlausD. even then its not working.

Comment: You have a couple of code glitches: 1. in line 4 it should be `==` instead of `=`. In line 5 it should be `parser.add_argument(...)` instead of `parser = add_argument(...)`. Does that fix your problem?

Answer (score 2):

There are, though, a couple of mistakes in your code. Here's the corrected version:

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-z', help = 'Help msg', required = True)

args, _ = parser.parse_known_args()

# value = some_functions(args.z)

if value == some_particular_value:
    parser.add_argument('-opp', '--operator', help = 'Some help msg', required = True)

    # args2, _ = parser.parse_known_args()
    # some_function2(args2.operator)
```

So, let's analyse your mistakes:

#### Assigning instead of comparing

That's typical newbie mistake. Within a conditional operator (`if`, `case`...) you **set** the value instead of **checking** it. The difference is in amount of the `=` sign.

If you assign value, the condition in the operator will be always `True` and test will always succeed (in most of programming languages and cases).

Check this out:

```
a = 1

if a = 2:
  print a
```

This *may* print `2` in some languages (like C or Java; using the correct syntax). Why? You've just set it! Yet, Python is smart enough to tell you about your mistake:

```
File "<stdin>", line 1
    if a = 2:
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

And compare it to this:

```
a = 1

if a == 2:
  print a
```

This will not print anything. Because the `if` test did not pass.

#### Assigning value instead of calling method

You want to be using the method `add_argument` instead of re-defining the `parser` variable, right?

```
parser = add_argument(...)
```

That's something like I've described above. You should be calling a method of a `parser` variable, not defining its new value:

```
parser.add_argument(...)
```

#### Re-parsing arguments is missing?

You did not show the part of the code where you check for the `operator` argument. Note: you should parse your arguments again, when defined a new argument:

```
parser.add_argument(...)
args, _ = parser.parse_known_arguments()
```

Then you will get a new argument in the `args` variable.

#### Using the wrong name of argument?

Again, you are missing part of code, where you check for the `operator` argument' value. If you are trying to access it with

```
args.opp # whoops...
```

Then you'd just get an error saying `There's no argument 'opp'!`, because it has its full name and should be accessed with it:

```
args.operator # aaah, here it is!
```

Comment: I made all the changes you told, but it is still having the same problem and also I am using the correct name of the operator.

Comment: @Vipul just show the exact code line where the error appears. I suppose you are missing something with the argument name while trying to access it...